# Можно ли использовать лямбды для инициализации функций в объявлении функции?

Tags: c++, lambda

Допустим есть такой псевдокод на c++. Какая-то функция(допустим сортировка), принимает какие-то значения и функцию-компаратор. Значения аргументов функций можно инициализировать по умолчанию. Можно ли что-нибудь подобное провести с компаратором, только инициализировав его лямбдой? Это удобно, например, если сортируются стандартные типы для которых уже определена операция сравнения.

```
template<class T, class BinaryFunc>
T testFunc(T t1, T t2, BinaryFunc func = [](T v1, T v2){return v1 < v2;}){
  return func(t1,t2);
}
```

И второй вопрос: ключевое слово `auto` определено только для стандартных типов? Или для пользовательских тоже?
зы: можно, конечно, переопределить эту фукнцию, но мне кажется, что так было бы лаконичней

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формально лямбда-выражения можно использовать в качестве аргументов по умолчанию. Однако аргументы по умолчанию не будут приниматься во внимание в процессе дедукции шаблонных аргументов. Это значит, что фактически тип `BinaryFunc` не будет дедуцироваться даже при успешно дедуцированном типе `T`. То есть "наруральный" синтаксис вызова функции работать не будет

```
int a = 5, b = 10;
testFunc(a, b); // Ошибка - невозможно дедуцировать тип `BinaryFunc`
```

Указать точный тип этого аргумента явно вручную вы не сможете, ибо тип лямбда-выражения вам неизвестен. Можно в качестве типа `BinaryFunc` указать `std::function<int(int, int)>` и это будет работать

```
int a = 5, b = 10;
testFunc<int, std::function<int(int, int)>>(a, b);
```

но в такой ситуации вообще пропадает необходимость в независимой шаблонной параметризации для этого параметра. Т.е. можно просто сделать так

```
template<class T>
T testFunc(T t1, T t2, 
           std::function<T(T, T)> func = [](T v1, T v2){return v1 < v2;})
{
  return func(t1, t2);
}
```

и забыть о необходимости дедуцировать тип этого аргумента. (Фактически основным предназначением `std::function` как раз и является такое избавление от шаблонной параметризации кода. Платой за это является потенциальная внутренняя неэффективность `std::function`.)

Вашу же исходную функциональность можно "сэмулировать" через перегрузку функции вместо использования аргумента по умолчанию

```
template<class T, class BinaryFunc>
T testFunc(T t1, T t2, BinaryFunc func)
{
  return func(t1, t2);
}

template<class T>
T testFunc(T t1, T t2)
{
  return testFunc(t1, t2, [](T v1, T v2){return v1 < v2;});
}
```

Comment: А что значит "дедуцироваться"'?

Comment: @Максим Петров: Значит: выводиться компилятором автоматически на основе типов фактических аргументов функции в точке вызова. Без дедукции шаблонных аргументов компилятором вам бы пришлось указывать шаблонные аргументы явно, через `<...>`, как у меня в примере выше.

Comment: `template<class T>
T testFunc(T t1, T t2, 
           std::function<int(int, int)> func = [](T v1, T v2){return v1 < v2;})
{
  return func(t1, t2);
}`

Comment: Этот вариант не компилится. Пишет, что не может зарезервировать переменные v1 и v2

Comment: через CLion запускаю

Comment: @Максим Петров: CLion - это IDE. А под ней лежит какой-то компилятор С++, который вызывается для компиляции кода.

Comment: @Максим Петров: Если уж реализуете шаблонную функцию,  проверяйте соответствие шаблонных параметров. `template<class T> 
T testFunc(const T& t1, const T& t2, std::function<T(const T&,const T&)> func = [](const T& v1, const T& v2){return v1 < v2;}) { return func(t1, t2);}`

Comment: @Максим Петров: Как правильно заметил Виктор Смирнов, я вас немного сбил с толку. Разумеется, должно быть `template<class T> T testFunc(T t1, T t2, std::function<T(T, T)> func = ...`. Исправил в ответе.

Comment: @AnT, ещё одна проблема возникла. Этот вариант работает, только если передавать туда лямбды. А как сделать так, чтобы можно было и указатели на функции передавать?
зы: в теме был ещё одни вопрос. ключевое слово `auto` определено только для стандартных типов? Или для пользовательских тоже?